# Can minecraft endermen spawn with dirt or grass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, creepers blow up dirt all the time and dirt is being destroyed constantly, and according to the wiki, dirt is not renewable, so eventually in old worlds, a dirt block may be considered loot. I was wondering about is there a possibility of dirt being renewable if endermen had a chance of spawning with dirt blocks or grass. Do endermen sometimes spawn with dirt blocks?

Comment: Do note that while dirt is not renewable, it is highly, highly, highly, highly unlikely that even on the oldest worlds you'll ever run out of it. Even the oldest worlds are 60,000,000 x 60,000,000 blocks large. So that's roughly 3,600 trillion blocks per layer. Assuming 5 layers of dirt, that's 18,000 trillion blocks of dirt. you're never going to use all of that unless you use that bacteria mod to consume all of it.

Comment: I assume by "loot", you mean "valuable". The word "loot" has a very specific meaning in Minecraft that refers to what drops from monsters, dungeon chests, fishing, and the like.

Comment: But in a server with a lot of players playing for years the dirt may be more valuable than emerald blocks. But still, that would be highly unlikely.

Comment: @myasadefa Let me rephrase that. If every single one of the 55 million monthly players had been mining one of those 18,000 trillion dirt blocks every second in the same server since version 1.0 of the game released in November 2011 without stopping to eat, sleep or rest, they would be done around March 2022. Trust me, you are not going to find any legitimate servers with a lack of dirt.

Comment: But, even though it is basically impossible to run out of dirt, the area you are in might in which case it would not be convenient to get more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No sources seem to indicate that they can spawn (naturally) with a block in their hand.  According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Moving_blocks), they instead *pickup* blocks within a 4x4x3 area of where they are standing.

Commands can be used to spawn them in holding a block, but other than that, if there is no dirt/grass for them to pickup, then they will never be holding said blocks.